# Would "Jr." be included with the family name or given name?

Tags: business-japanese

On the application that I am filling out, they have split up the name section into three parts much like any English application, but instead of 'Last name' it says 'Family name'. I usually put my last name and add a 'jr.' at the end, but my last name is my family name, not 'jr.' So is it ok for me to put my last name and add a 'jr.' for the family name field, or would I put the 'jr.' elsewhere.

Comment: If Jr. is part of your legal name you jould inculde it in the family name cell other wise just drop it. In any case, if you can drop it I strongly advice to drop it. Because unless you're father is also there there can't be confusion anyway.

Comment: Jr. is a part of my legal name and as an emergency contact I have listed my father, so in that case I guess I would put 'Jr.' with my family name. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Authorities could be perplexed jr. who? I think you'd better go to and ask the certain municipal or you can namewhere you had gone to which had given the sheet.

Comment: http://www.atlanta.us.emb-japan.go.jp

Answer (score 1):

Your mother (and a possible sibling) is a Watson, and your last name is the same as hers. I doubt she is a "junior" so I would not put it as last name.

You and your father are both Richard, but you are "Richard Jr." so I would add it to your first name.

Most people in the USA know a lot of "Richard Jr"s or some people who just use "Junior" as their first name by default.